# How to decode string from bytes 32 in event log that is returned as hex on event log subscribe

Tags: abi, encoding, decoding

I am using the web3.eth.subscribe method to listen for events on a contract.

When an event occurs, I am using the web3.eth.abi.decodeLog to decode the data from the event.

One of the parameters I am decoding, contentHash, is a bytes32 parameter:

```
         {
            "indexed":false,
            "internalType":"bytes32",
            "name":"contentHash",
            "type":"bytes32"
         }
```

It is returned in hex form from web3.eth.abi.decodeLog. For example: 0xf0cec612a42da185c30ae13568d292045e625f045de30e3fea157a011484119f

However when I go to etherscan, I see it is in a string, this is what I need:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x85233656b070cd4df1555dd9b93d650e860f29795914409a4fee12fc43f3e8b6#eventlog

How does etherscan decode the hex to string? I've tried web3.utils.hexToAscii and web3.utils.hexToUtf8 and neither works.

---

Update:

I tried using abi-decoder

```
    web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x85233656b070cd4df1555dd9b93d650e860f29795914409a4fee12fc43f3e8b6", function(e, receipt) {
      const decodedLogs = abiDecoder.decodeLogs(receipt.logs);
      console.log(decodedLogs[0].events)
    });
```

returns

```
  {
    name: 'contentHash',
    type: 'bytes32',
    value: '0xf0cec612a42da185c30ae13568d292045e625f045de30e3fea157a011484119f'
  }
```

While etherscan shows F0CEC612A42DA185C30AE13568D292045E625F045DE30E3FEA157A011484119F

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x85233656b070cd4df1555dd9b93d650e860f29795914409a4fee12fc43f3e8b6#eventlog

---

Update II

Subscription code (there are a lot of events that will be logged here be aware of that)

```
const editionInputs = [
         {
            "indexed":false,
            "internalType":"uint256",
            "name":"quantity",
            "type":"uint256"
         },
         {
            "indexed":false,
            "internalType":"uint256",
            "name":"price",
            "type":"uint256"
         },
         {
            "indexed":false,
            "internalType":"address",
            "name":"fundingRecipient",
            "type":"address"
         },
         {
            "indexed":true,
            "internalType":"uint256",
            "name":"editionId",
            "type":"uint256"
         },
         {
            "indexed":false,
            "internalType":"bytes32",
            "name":"contentHash",
            "type":"bytes32"
         }
      ]
const subscriptionEdition = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
  address: '0xaf89C5E115Ab3437fC965224D317d09faa66ee3E',
  topics:['0xaf0358e6610affb68df2bc72a3c7cba9f34af8963e36ee890142b81bf3c8ba69'],
  fromBlock:0
  }).on("data", async function(log){
    console.log(log)
    const logData = web3.eth.abi.decodeLog(editionInputs, log.data, log.topics)
    console.log(logData)
  }).on("error", function(err){
    console.log("err", err)
  })
```

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the same transaction? Subscribe should call with the same value than etherscan. How are you subscribing, can you show more details returned by subscribe callback?

Comment: The simplest way to test it is with the web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt I put above, since that will return just one log. You can add the abi from the verified contract 0xaf89c5e115ab3437fc965224d317d09faa66ee3e, run that and see the contentHash returned will be 0xf0cec612a42da185c30ae13568d292045e625f045de30e3fea157a011484119f
while etherscan is
F0CEC612A42DA185C30AE13568D292045E625F045DE30E3FEA157A011484119F

Comment: I'll add the subscription code though for reference

Comment: Also if you use a tool like tenderly to look at the transaction 0x85233656b070cd4df1555dd9b93d650e860f29795914409a4fee12fc43f3e8b6
it will also show the hex format, not the string that etherscan shows. So etherscan is doing some additional decoding step that I cannot find documented anywhere.

Comment: It is working correctly. The only difference is that Etherscan removes the 0x prefix and show the rest as uppercase. In the explorer you can switch the output view to hex and it will show the content of the whole 'data' field  with a 0x prefix and in lowercase.

Comment: Oh wow haha can't believe I didn't see that. thanks